# How to add multiple images in single image view and to show all images for every 2 second continuously

Tags: ios, swift, image

I have one view controller and I kept one full mage view in that view controller.And i have some image name like 1.png,2.png,3.png , like 6 images.What I need is I need to show as like slide .i.e for every 2 second one image should be in image view. I have done it in Objective-C. But I am beginner in Swift, so not able to do it. How to do this?

```
@implementation ViewController {
    UIImageView* imgView; // your UIImageView
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    UIImage* img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.jpg"];
    UIImage* img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"s2.jpg"];


   imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; // create a UIImageView with the same size as the view.
    imgView.animationImages = @[img1, img2]; // use a nice NSArray literal to pass in your images.
    imgView.animationDuration = 2.0*2.0; // 2 seconds for each image (x3 images)
    [self.view addSubview:imgView]; // add UIImageView to view

    [imgView startAnimating]; // start animating
}
```

Like that in Swift I need to do :

I am having image view name as `imagview`.And please don't compare the Obj-C code. Because there I have added some library file for animating. Can i code to do this continuous image showing for every 2 seconds in Swift?

Comment: what type direction you have preferred?

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P  in horizontal direction

Comment: i think you want scrolling with image right?

Comment: can you try the "AOScrollerView" file which is use to scroll image with direction right or left.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var imagesListArray = [UIImage]()

for imageName in 1...3
{
    imagesListArray.append(UIImage(named: "\(imageName).png")!)
}

// You can also use below code to add images if not want to use loop    
// imagesListArray.append(UIImage(named: "1.png")!)
// imagesListArray.append(UIImage(named: "2.png")!)
// imagesListArray.append(UIImage(named: "3.png")!)

self.imageView.animationImages = imagesListArray
self.imageView.animationDuration = 2.0
self.imageView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: `self.imageView.startAnimating()` is an library file for obj c.Thats why i was not able to do code for thst

Comment: You can use startAnimating in swift also.

Comment: No library should i needed ??..Startanimating is for swift uiimage view property or what ??

Comment: There is no need for any additional library. using`startAnimating()` you can animate images inside `animationImages` array. to stop animation you can use `stopAnimating()`

Comment: i am getting error that , ` Cannot assign value of type 'NSMutableArray' to type '[UIImage]?'`.And i have one more doubt .I have 3 image namely 1.png,2.png,3.png.How can i assign all images to uiimage and make the for loop ?

Comment: @mark answer updated for swift 2.x ... please try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let urlStringArr : NSArray = tempDic["get_image"] as? NSArray
        {
            if urlStringArr.count != 0
            {

                var imagesListArray = [UIImage]()
                if urlStringArr.count > 1
                {
                    for i in 0..<urlStringArr.count
                    {
                        let url = URL(string:urlStringArr[i] as! String)
                        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                        {
                            let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!
                            imagesListArray.append(image)
                        }
                    }

                     cell.imagePet.animationImages = imagesListArray
                     cell.imagePet.animationDuration = 5.0
                     cell.imagePet.startAnimating()

                }
                else
                {
                    if let getUrlString : String = urlStringArr[0] as? String
                    {
                        if getUrlString != ""
                        {
                            cell.imagePet.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:getUrlString), placeholderImage:nil)
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Xcode 11.3.1 and Swift 5.2.

Say you have an image array and UIImageView as follows:

```
var images = [UIImage]()
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

Then you can set all `images` to `UIImageView` and start animating by following code:

```
imageView.animationImages = images
imageView.animationDuration = 2 * images.count
imageView.startAnimating()
```

The `animationDuration` is the amount of time it takes to go through one cycle of the images.